# sails.js + passport.js req.user is undefined

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js

I am using sails.js as backend / API and angular js as frontend.

The server and the client are on different domain.

When I authentify my user with passport, I set the session of sails with the user object.

Then when I am authentified and I start a new request from my front to list products, on my server (sails.js) req.user is undefined and in my session there is not the user I created.

How can I sort out this issue? I would like to setup the current user as a session on my backend to avoid retrieving it everytime with id. I will have better performance.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.

You need to add this line in angularjs app.js

$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you login/signup return the user data as API instead of using seasons.

Comment: It means that I will need to send my user object for all request? I think it's not good for the performance. I already send the id. Then I could perform a user.findone .... But is there a solution to keep object in sessions? Sails is running. It should keep the object in the sessions. No?

Comment: For the login request you should pass in the credentials and return a token/user data + token. Now whenever you want to make a request use the token. That way you wont have to pass the credentials every time. You should have a ready access token in your passport collection for each user